# Matplotlib transparent face settings

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

My goal is to make a matplotlib barchart that has only the label names on a single axis, then bars, and then the value of those bars at the top [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7v2w.jpg). However, I want to be able to embed an image like this online and want the background to be transparent. But when I savefig as `transparent=True` it comes out [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyLFt.jpg) There are these lines in the background that are very distracting and the names of my y labels become transparent as well which I don't want.

I just need help gaining more control over transparency parameters.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 12), frameon=False)

# x dummy data
x = prez_counts['presidents']

# y dummy data
y = prez_counts['occurence']

# make facecolor transparent
ax.set_facecolor('w')
ax.patch.set_alpha(0)

# plot bar plot
ax.barh(x,y,color=sns.color_palette("gnuplot_r", len(x)), alpha=0.7)

# remove xaxis ticks
ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)

# add x values of y to end of bars
for i, v in enumerate(y):
    ax.text(v + .5, i - .20, str(v), fontsize=(8))

sns.despine(left=True, bottom=True, right=True, top=True)
plt.tight_layout()

plt.savefig('../3_output/test.png', transparent=True)
```

I would like the output to be the same plot, just without the lines in the background and without clear/translucent y labels.

Comment: When I run your code it looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FdJw.png) which is fine.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Why would there be that discrepancy? And can you overlay the image so that where the grey background is shows what's behind it?

Comment: The gray is the background. The discrepancy is because you apparently have some other code which isn't shown here.

Comment: I just copied and pasted it back onto my local from here and ran it but still got lines in the background. My `x` and `y` are pandas series, could that make a difference?

Comment: The thing is: You cannot copy and paste it really, because it's not runnable. So if you can provide a fully runnable code here, we can both copy paste it and check for differences. See [mcve] or http://sscce.org